# In excel, how to quickly let the cursor to focus on data when I want to select the range of them?

Tags: excel

When I insert one chart in excel, the generated chart will always on the top of the data. However, if I want to select some range of my data to the chart, I usually have to drag the chart away from the top of data for locating the cursor on them. 
My question: is there any simple and quick way to switch to focus on one of the data and the chart while hiding the other?

Answer (score 1):

Not a perfect answer, but you can adjust the transparency of the fill of the chart object. Then, click on a cell and use the arrow keys to select the cells of interest behind the chart ...

[image]